# how to order an array with the number of repetitions in javascript

Tags: javascript, arrays

how can I order this array by the number of repetitions, for example, if the number is repeated once, it should be shown first, if it is shown 3, you see later, and so on.

from this

```
10,8,1,1,1,4,4,5,5,5,5
```

to his

```
10,8,4,4,1,1,1,5,5,5,5
```

I tried to do a for dive to break it apart and then use height to be able to get the amount of repetitions but it is very complicated for me

Comment: `console.log(arr.sort((a, b) => arr.filter((el) => el === a).length - arr.filter((el) => el === b).length))` - not very efficient but if your arrays are small it's fine

Comment: @migcat Does it matter that repetition 1 is 10, 8 and not 8, 10 in the expected results? Doesn't matter that 10 is greater than 8?

Answer (score 5):

You can use a custom "sort" function. In this case, you want to be able to sort by the number of instances in the input array, so you can calculate a map of counts to use as a reference when sorting

```js
/*
from this
10,8,1,1,1,4,4,5,5,5,5
to his
10,8,4,4,1,1,1,5,5,5,5
*/

const input = [10,8,1,1,1,4,4,5,5,5,5];

const counts = input.reduce((a, c) => {
  a[c] = (a[c] || 0) + 1;
  return a;
}, {});

console.log({counts});

console.log(input.sort((a, b) => {
  return counts[a] - counts[b];
}));
```

Comment: This is the correct way to do this with `O(n)` complexity

Comment: @mhodges no, `.sort` can't be O(n)

Comment: If the number of unique values (m) is greatly smaller than the number of values (n), creating a set of unique values and then sorting, spreading all the unique values again would be O(n + m log m + n) which could be better than O(n + n log n)

Comment: @JonasWilms Sorry, I meant strictly for getting the counts. Yes, `.sort` is `O(nlog(n))`. And you're absolutely correct - it depends on what the data looks like to determine the optimal algorithm